# Как вывести уникальные сочетания в диапазоне?

Tags: excel, случайные-числа

У меня есть 50 изображений и 100 карточек, на каждой карточке 10 ячеек (а-ля лото). Соответственно, мне нужно 100 уникальных сочетаний чисел от 1 до 50.

Я находила решения через формулы в Excel, но там получается гигантский массив вида (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11), а мне нужно, чтобы выводилось только 100 строк из массива, при этом случайных - типа (2, 44, 35, 1, 14, 50, 32,  4, 39, 17 // 38, 25, 47, 3, 29, 12, 19, 21, 46, 30 и так далее).

Мне это нужно по дизайнерской работе, я совсем не программист... Могу только в коде переменные на свои поменять и в онлайн-компилятор засунуть, язык программирования не важен, задача на один раз.

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
import random
for i in range(100):
    print(random.sample(range(1,51), 10))
```